# Linux 30-digit random number generator

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I've been given a following task that must be completed in linux command-line.

Using either `for`, `while` or `until` create a script in the linux command-line that generates 30-digit random numbers with:

```
a) no delay
b) 2 seconds delay
```

And I honestly have no idea how to proceed with this. It can't include python or perl.
I'm just a beginner so any help appreciated!

Comment: And we don't do homeworks for free ^^

Comment: So far I've tested the possibilities of `tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 30` but this is not what I am looking for as the outcome looked much like: `<numbers here>server:~$`

Given that python is also excluded, I cannot use `'import random as R; print(R.randint()`

Comment: ^^ How does `tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 30; echo` look? :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# wait 2 seconds or use "sleep 2"
SECONDS=0; while [ $SECONDS -ne 2 ]; do :; done

n=""
for ((i=0;i<30;i++)); do n+="$(($RANDOM%10))"; done; echo "$n"
```

---

See: `help while`, `help test` and `help for`

Comment: Thank you! That basically solved the whole problem! I thought I can't use $RANDOM that way. Knowledge gained!

Comment: Why is there a sleep for 2 seconds?

Comment: @anishsane: OP asked for a 2 seconds delay.

Comment: Oh... :D... I thought it was for something like seed initialization :P

Answer (score 0):

Here we grab one number from 0..255

```
n=`dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=1 status=none | od -tu1 -Anone`
```

I leave doing the mapping of that into 0..9 and doing it 30 times as an exercise for the student....